# How to input text in java using the comand console?

Tags: java

I would like to input a copied text from a text processor or others. 
Using `nextLine()` just introduces the first line and it doesn't let me use `StringBuffer` too. I haven't found anything to solve my problem.

This is my code:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuffer lines= new StringBuffer();
    String line;

    System.out.println("texto:");
    line= keyboard.nextLine();
    //lines= keyboard.nextLine(); //this doesn´t work
    System.out.println(lines);
}
```

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

I copy this text from a text file:

> ksjhbgkkg
>
> sjdjjnsfj
>
> sdfjfjjjk

Then, I paste it on the cmd (I use Geany).
I would like to be able to get a StringBuffer or similar (something I can manipulate) like this:

`StringBuffer x = "ksjhbgkkgsjdjjnsfjsdfjfjjjk"`

Thanks!

Comment: How about adding the read line to the StringBuffer? How about reading more than just one line (since you have three in your example)?

Comment: Why not use java.util.Scanner?

Comment: @Laurel `Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);` ... what do think about this existing line of code?

Comment: @Tom You can use Scanner on files :)

Comment: @Laurel And on much more, but this isn't what you've asked there.

Comment: @Tom That's why it's a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like:

```
while(keyboard.hasNextLine()) {
     line = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

You could then store those lines. (e.g. an array/ArrayList).

Answer (score 0):

You can append the keyboard.nextLine() to your stringBuffer like so:

```
 lines.append(keyboard.nextLine());
```

StringBuffer will accept a String to be appended so this should fit your purposes.

You could use this with the while loop as shown by @Cache which would give something like:

```
 while (keyboard.hasNextLine()) {
      lines.append(keyboard.nextLine());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cache Staheli has the right approach. To elaborate on how you can put the keyboard input into your `StringBuffer`, consider this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuffer lines= new StringBuffer();
    String line;

    System.out.println("texto:");       

    while(keyboard.hasNextLine() ) { // while there are more lines to read
        line = keyboard.nextLine();  // read the next line
        if(line.equals("")) {        // if the user entered nothing (i.e. just pressed Enter)
            break;                   // break out of the input loop
        }

        lines.append(line);         // otherwise append the line to the StringBuffer
    }

    System.out.println(lines);      // print the lines that were entered
    keyboard.close();               // and close the Scanner
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, it let me introduce new lines, but i can't go out of the WHILE ... so I never reach the System.out.println(lines). I tried to add a condition like: while(keyboard.hasNextLine() && keyboard.nextLine!="0") but it didn't work... (I am a begginer so, maybe shouldn't I press Enter?) Thanks for your previous answer!

Comment: It's because the input stream `System.in` is never closed unless you close it yourself (you can do this on Windows if you hold Ctrl+D). For the purpose of this program, you might want to use a particular entry to indicate the end of the input. For example, you might want to make it so that if the user press Enter, you end the program. See my edited answer for an example, and note that the Scanner.nextLine() method will consume the new line from the input, so we want to detect the empty string "" and not the new line character "\n".